# Date range in EE postmaster template

Tags: php, embeds, postmaster

I have a notification setup that is pulling the top 5 most viewed entries within the specific channel, and I want to send this email with the top 5 most viewed entries, and I want to send this notification out every 2 weeks. Below is the line of PHP code that I embedded to the notification as well as the channel entry calling it. Its showing just the top 5 most viewed overall still and is not resetting.

```
<?php
        $start_time = ee()->localize->format_date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i', ee()->localize->now - (60*60*24*14));
?>

    {embed="_embeds/two-weeks-php"}
{exp:channel:entries start_on="<?php echo $start_time; ?>" site="example" channel="blog" dynamic="no" limit="10" status="open|Preview" {global:disable_basic} orderby="view_count_one"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is PHP parsing set on input or output?? Also, It's wack (j/k) to use PHP in a template when things like http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date exists (I don't work for them but I use that free addon all over).

Answer (score 0):

if the dynamic timespan is your problem, try using

```
start_on="-2 Weeks"
```

and (optional)

`stop_before="{current_time}"`

and first try to test it with a regular template. You will not need an addon

I would try to avoid using php

Gabriel